# Notification of unsuitability of procedures

Tags: discussion

While I am aware this goes into the meta part, I have no priviledges to do so.

> The suitability of this type of question is up for debate. Until such issues are officially resolved, this question will be locked. At the moment, the current opinion of this type of question involving the identification of adult-orient anime is that it is not suitable on out site, but your opinion and suggestions in the matter are welcome in the meta post mentioned above.

Except I dont have priviledges to chat, comment, or ask or answer at the meta. This question is the only way I can voice any of my opinions. I believe this should be accounted for in the future, so other new members, such as me, do not have to go through the trouble of messing up the site like this to notify you of this.

Yep, sorry about messing up the way things are to be.

Comment: @Krazer Note this, please.

Comment: All you need is 5 rep to participate in meta. You are free to comment in this post or you can get access by contributing to the site in other ways. Providing edits to that [are approved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) will net you 2 rep each.

Comment: I see, that should be a possibility. Concerning the locked question, is the unsuitability of the NSFW content tha main problem, or is the identification nature of the question a problem as well? Because if it's the former, the main problems will lie in the answers, I guess.

Comment: @user2898 The problem is that StackExchange (the parent company of this site) prohibits sexually explicit material. Personally, I have no problem with it as long as it's clearly labeled NSFW. (and in your case it is since you included "Hentai" in the title) But we need an official response from the StackExchange.

Comment: Related: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/questions/755/how-should-we-handle-potentially-nsfw-content-from-questions-and-answers